# whats the difference between these create methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hey I am stuck with my orientation in rails.

I got a User model, a Course Model and a CourseEnrollment Model.

When I want to add a link in my Course Index View like

```
link_to 'join' CourseEnrollment.create(:course_id => course.id, :user_id => current_user)
```

Does this create method belong to my Model? I am confused because in my User Model I defined a method that uses `role_assignments.create(.....)`. What is the difference between these 2 create methods? I cant use course_enrollments.create by the way. Thx for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit confused as to what you're asking, but I'll try my best.

(First of all, in your example, `current_user` should probably be `current_user.id`.)

When you call `CourseEnrollment.create`, you are simply creating a new `CourseEntrollment` model with the specified attributes.

Assuming that your `User` model `has_many :role_assignments`:

When you call `@role_assignments.create` from within your `User` model, Rails automatically creates the association for you (e.g. sets the `user_id` to the `id` of the user). This doesn't have to be done within the model itself, though:

`current_user.role_assignments.create(...) # automatically sets the association`

Assuming that your `User` model *also* `has_many :course_enrollments`, the following will create a `CourseEnrollment` model and automatically associate it with the current user:

`current_user.course_enrollments.create(...)`

Comment: hey thx for your reply. So could I also use `current_user.course_enrollments.create(:course_id => course.id, :user_id => current_user` instead of `CourseEnrollment.create(...)` in my view?

Comment: You wouldn't have to manually set the `:user_id`, but other than that, you could. **However**, that should probably be happening in your controller, not your view!